# htaccess email regex

Tags: .htaccess, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to write a patter in such a way that this link :

http://www.mysite.com/link/go/emailadress@gmail.com

is interpreted like this :

http://www.mysite.com/process.php?email=emailadress@gmail.com

But i dont know how to write. I tryied this but it is not working. Need help please.

This what I wrote in my .htaccess file but not working :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule    ^link/go/overview/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$    /process.php?email=$1    [NC,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
RewriteRule link/go/(.*)$ process.php?email=$1
```

This seems to work. You should do the email validation in `process.php`, not in the `.htaccess` rule for the sake of readability (plus, you can at least have a nice error message on the page).

This works because anything after `link/go/` will be matched (`.` matches any character, so `.*` means match any character as many times as it can, and `(.*)` means save this into `$1` - The `$` at the end means end of line, so it'll match all the way to the end).

What you tried won't work because `[A-Za-z0-9-]+` will only match letters and numbers, no `@` or `.`.

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: I've tested it and it works, so I'm standing by the answer - you might have a conflicting rule elsewhere. Can you paste your entire `.htaccess` into the question?

Comment: Ok, I read your explanation, but it is not working

Comment: ok let me paste it :

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/link/go/(.*)$ /process.php?email=$1

Comment: There is no `^` in my answer. Please copy and paste it as-is and let me know :-)

Comment: No worries, if you could accept the answer by pressing the green hollow tick on the left, I'd appreciate it :-)

Comment: For what it's worth, here's an example of doing more robust email validation in the regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

I agree with Jay that it should be done in the PHP code though.

Comment: btw here is a good cheat sheet for mod_rewrite which can be handy. http://www.addedbytes.com/download/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet-v2/png/